# Roles base on item in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles

I am quite new with programming and my English is quite bad so I am sorry if this post confused you.

I am implementing a basic ASP .NET MVC web application that will manage information of companies.
There are two pages in this application.
One is for viewing the information, which does not require anything to access this page.
Another one is for edit the information which you can access this page if only you have Admin role of the company.

```
    public ActionResult ViewInfo(string companyId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult EditInfo(string companyId)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If I have an account that can access to 2 companies but the account has completely different roles on both of the companies. (e.g. the account is admin of Company A and normal user of Company B).

Is there any easy way to get the Role base on what company that I am going to access to? I've tried using custom RoleProvider but it seems that I cannot pass additional parameters to the method.

Somewhat like this?

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
          string companyId = GetCompanyId();    // Is there any good way to get this companyId from the Controller?
          return userCompanyRoles.Any(u => u.Username == username && u.CompanyId == companyId && u.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == roleName));
    }

    ...

}
```

**EDIT**

There are 4 models in my application:

```
   public class User {
       public string Id { get; set;}
       ...
   }

    public class Company {
       public string Id { get; set;}
       ...
    }

    public class Role {
       public string Name { get; set;}
       ...
    }

    public class UserCompanyRoles {
       public string UserId { get; set; }
       public string CompanyId { get; set; }
       public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

So the table look like this

```
UserId   CompanyId   Role
   1        A         User
   1        A         Admin
   1        B         User
   2        B         Admin
   2        C         User
   3        A         Admin
   3        C         Admin
```

Comment: Are you ever expected to have more then 2 companies?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Sure! and there will be more pages for different roles too.

Answer (score 0):

The membership provider controls the roles that each user has. It normally does this on a user by user basis, rather than on a user/company. 
You are already doing the right thing by using `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

However it sounds like you want to check if the current user has access to the current company. You could do that a bit like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult EditInfo(string companyId)
{
    if (UserHasAccessToCompany(companyId))
    {
        return View();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private bool UserHasAccessToCompany(string companyId)
{
    var company = companyRepository.GetCompanyById(companyId); // making the assumption you have a repository for companies
    return company.Users.Select(u => u.userId).Include(User.Identity.Name); // you can access the current user using the `User` from within the controller
}
```

Assuming you might want to check if the User has access a lot this function could be moved into a `BaseController` so you can access it everywhere.

Comment: This is not quite right.

I have 4 repositories which are:

User, Role, Company, UserCompanyRoles

I will edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: OK so change the logic in the `UserHasAccessToCompany` function so it returns the correct answer. Keep in mind that you might be bending the membership/role pattern a lot by adding in different roles per company. I have doubts about whether what you are trying to do is possible in a filter because you need to pass in a variable to know which company it is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute for this porpouse, because you need user may see the same view in differ way dependenly on role in company. But if you add`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`, user will always see it as Admin.

So, I assume, you are having two models - `User class` from Membership and `Company class` like this

```
public class Company
{
  public int companyID {get; set;}
  public straing companyName {get; set;}
}
```

The simplest solution, as for me, is to have third join table with roles:

```
//In real application userID will be Guid if you use Membership and int if you use SimpleMembership

    userID  companyID    role
      1        2        "Admin"
      1        3         "User"

public class MyRole
{
public Guid userID {get; set;} 
public int companyID {get; set;}
public string roleName {get; set;}

}
```

Now you may use it as follows:

```
public ActionResult CompanyDetails (int id)
{
   var user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
   Guid currentUserID = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
   MyRole userRole = db.MyRoles.Where(g=>g.userID = currentUserID & g.companyID = id); // get user role
   string roleName = userRole.roleName; // get role name

   bool isAdmin = roleName == "Admin"? true : false;

   if(isAdmin)
   {
    //return as for admin

   }
   else
   {
    // return as for user
    }

}
```

Comment: This might be a solution but doesn't this mean I need to put that filtering code for every View I am going to have? I am thinking of using a custom RoleProvider that can return the right Role for the user according to the companyId that he is going to access to. So that I can just simply the Authorize tag with Role filtering in every View I am going to have. But I am not sure that it is possible or it is a good practice.

Comment: @BPRW You may try to create custom action filter, based on that filtering: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters